# Issue with WebView on Javafx 8

Tags: webview, javafx-8

I am have an issue with WebView component. Sometimes if the application stays idle for a few minutes, the display is just a blank screen and WebView is not rendered on the stage. Other times it works perfectly fine. Also once a particular webView component fails to render onto the screen, all other webViews through out the application fail to load.

The component behaves very inconsistently and I couldn't identify a definitive pattern to replicate the issue.

I appreciate if any of you experts can point me out in the right direction to fix this inconsistent behavior.

---

### My WebView code:

```
String htmlBillText = billTextController.transformBillXmlXsl();

WebView webView = new WebView();
WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
engine.setOnError((WebErrorEvent event) -> {
    // NEVER GOES INTO THIS AT ALL
    System.out.println("event.getMessage()::"+event.getMessage());
    System.out.println("event.getException()::"+event.getException().getMessage());
    System.out.println("event.toString()::"+event.toString());
    engine.reload();
});

engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {

        System.out.println("oldState::" + oldState);
        System.out.println("newState::" + newState);
        if (engine.getLoadWorker().getException() != null) {
            System.out.println("engine.getLoadWorker().getException()::" + engine.getLoadWorker().getException().getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (engine.getLoadWorker().getException() != null && newState == Worker.State.FAILED) {
            System.out.println(engine.getLoadWorker().getException().getMessage());
        }

        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            System.out.println("engine.getDocument()::"+engine.getDocument());
            if (engine.getDocument() != null) {
                String html = (String) engine.executeScript("document.documentElement.innerHTML");
                if (StringUtils.isEmpty(html)) {
                    System.out.println("FX WebView Engine Failed To Load Content... Execute Reload...");
                    engine.reload();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("engine.getTitle()::" + engine.getTitle());
            System.out.println("engine.getLocation()::" + engine.getLocation());
            System.out.println("engine.getUserAgent()::" + engine.getUserAgent());
            System.out.println("engine.getUserDataDirectory()::" + engine.getUserDataDirectory());
            System.out.println("engine.isJavaScriptEnabled()::" + engine.isJavaScriptEnabled());
        }
    }
});
engine.loadContent(htmlBillText);
```

---

### MY DISPLAY CONSOLE WHEN WEBVIEW FAILS TO LOAD:

```
oldState::READY
newState::SCHEDULED
oldState::SCHEDULED
newState::RUNNING
oldState::RUNNING
newState::SUCCEEDED
engine.getDocument()::[object HTMLDocument]
engine.getTitle()::SB6:v98#DOCUMENT
engine.getLocation()::
engine.getUserAgent()::Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/538.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) JavaFX/8.0 Safari/538.19
engine.getUserDataDirectory()::null
engine.isJavaScriptEnabled()::true
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks -Sv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug has been raised and the progress can be tracked below:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8175170

Thanks. -SV